# Change of index variable of summation (proof).

Tags: real-analysis, summation

Using this definition of finite series:

[image]

I'm trying to prove part (b):

[image]

It seems this should be easy to prove, but I can't seem to do it using just the definition and (a).

Comment: May I ask which textbook you are studying?

Comment: Induction over $k$ works.

Comment: @Akira I think it's from Analysis I by Terence Tao.

Comment: Thank you so much @amsmath! You are totally correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since for all $i$, if we define $j:=i+k$, then $a_i=a_{j-k}$, then the sequence ${(a_i)}_{i=m}^n$ is identical to the sequence ${(a_{j-k})}_{j=m+k}^{n+k}$.  So too must be the series be identical. $$\sum_{i=m}^n a_i=\sum_{j=m+k}^{n+k}a_{j-k}$$

---

By induction: $${a_m=a_{(m+k)-k}\\~\\\forall n\geq m:\left[\sum_{i=m}^{n}a_i=\sum_{j=m+k}^{n+k}a_{j-k}~~\to~~a_{n+1}+\sum_{i=m}^{n}a_i=a_{(n+k)+1-k}+\sum_{j=m+k}^{n+k}a_{j-k}\right]}$$ So...

Comment: I considered the first part too, but then how does the definition guarantee that identical sequences give identical series.

Comment: You are adding the exact same terms.

Comment: @BrettLane good question, it is a property of the real numbers field I guess!

Answer (score 0):

If $n<m$, then $n+k<m+k$ and so both sums are equal to $0$.

Otherwise, you can prove it by induction on $n-m$.